# kadmin can't find master key

Tags: debian, kerberos

I can't use the kadmin.local interface I just get the error `Authenticating as principal root/admin@deadpool.cavill.org.uk with password.
kadmin.local: Can not fetch master key (error: No such file or directory). while initializing kadmin.local interface`

This occured after I used `addprinc root` and `addprinc root/admin` and used the command `kinit`. Which returns the error `kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'deadpool.cavill.org.uk' while getting initial credentials`.

I checked my config and that looks fine. I would check the krb5kdc error log but there isn't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting he contents of /etc/krb5kdc and then using sudo krb5_newrealm to recreate the realm. After I added the principals again and used kinit it worked fine.

Comment: I had the same issue on Centos, and it was resolved by deleting everything as follows:
rm -rf /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/*

Answer (score 0):

Those solution are not good imho

If give the message "can't find master key"

need that master key is still not created

To re-create or create use

```
kdb5_util stash
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> kadmin.local: Can not fetch master key (error: No such file or directory). while
> initializing kadmin.local interface
> ```

I fixed this by fulling initializing my kerberos database:

```
kdb5_util create -s
```